# Block multiple requests on a deleted file

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I hosted a JavaScript file on my server running Wordpress on Nginx. I removed the file but there are still several requests from multiple referrers. These referrers are from different URLs and IP addresses.

There are a LOT of requests and I want to block them cause it seems to affect my server's performance.

Is there a way that I can block these requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that you'll get a performance gain when you configure nginx explicitely that the location of old javascript is no longer valid, as nginx won't need to check the filesystem anymore, and when you send a 410 error it won't need to send the 404 error page either:

```
location /path/to/script.js {
return 410 ; 
}
```

HTTP status code 410: Gone

> The requested resource is no longer available at the server and no
>   forwarding address is known. This condition is expected to be
>   considered permanent. Clients with link editing capabilities SHOULD
>   delete references to the Request-URI after user approval. If the
>   server does not know, or has no facility to determine, whether or not
>   the condition is permanent, the status code 404 (Not Found) SHOULD be
>   used instead. This response is cacheable unless indicated otherwise.
>
> The 410 response is primarily intended to assist the task of web
>   maintenance by notifying the recipient that the resource is
>   intentionally unavailable and that the server owners desire that
>   remote links to that resource be removed. Such an event is common for
>   limited-time, promotional services and for resources belonging to
>   individuals no longer working at the server's site. It is not
>   necessary to mark all permanently unavailable resources as "gone" or
>   to keep the mark for any length of time -- that is left to the
>   discretion of the server owner.

Comment: I added this directive but it's still giving off a 404 instead of a 401. I'm accepting this as the answer as this lead me to a better direction. Thanks!

Comment: You could use an `error 404 "404 file not found" ; ` to send a simple message, straight from memory instead of the more userfriendly error_file you may have had configured elsewhere. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
location = /deleted.js {
    default_type    text/plain;
    return      410 "410";
    #access_log off;
}
```

You might either want to disable the access log as above, or, if you're running a new enough nginx, configure [`access_log`](http://nginx.org/r/access_log) to do buffering.  Disc access is generally very expensive, and is likely what's slowing you down.

BTW, using `return` automatically implies `log_not_found off;`, so, it's already better than simply leaving it to vfs to have the 404 generated.

Comment: I turned off the `access_log` as you said, disc writes are costly. Thanks. If I can upvote this I would.

Answer (score 2):

This is an idea using iptable's string module to check the http header content, of course it must be adapted to your special case: http://spamcleaner.org/en/misc/w00tw00t.html

However I'm not really sure about what would be faster between inspecting all of the incoming packets and having your webserver handle them. I'd eventually instead just add a line in the server configuration to immediately return a 404 on that specific url; traffic will self decrease with time, as webmasters and search engines correct their links (and they will, as 404 errors would cause a bad positioning in modern web search engines).